# How to use re.search() to check if string is a float in python?

Tags: python

```
def checkFloat(string):
#check if float
#if float return true
#else
    return False
```

Trying to create a simple code that will check if a string is a float. If it is a float, it should return true. Otherwise, it will return false. How can I use re.search() to go about this?

Comment: The answer: Just google it.

Comment: Why does it have to use a regular expression?